# Already selected values from DropDown list dynamically updating on multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

after googling for 2 days and trying to figure it out myself and failing, i came here to ask for some help.
The problem which i want to solve: I have mulitple sheets, where are ranges with selectable cells from the Drop-Down lists, and 1 sheet where the source of the DropDown list is located. What i wanted is that the already selected cells from the drop down list to dynamically update if i change it from the source from the drop down. I have already found a code that works like a charm, on one sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim count_cells As Integer
Dim new_value As String
Dim old_value As String
Dim rng As Range
For count_cells = 1 To Range("I1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
    Set rng = Worksheets("Part Database").Range("C3:C11")
    If Intersect(Target, Range("I" & count_cells + 1)) Is Nothing Then
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        new_value = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        old_value = Target.Value
        Target.Value = new_value
        rng.Replace What:=old_value, Replacement:=new_value
        Target.Select
    End If
Next count_cells
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

code works perfectly, but i want it to work on multiple sheets, is it even possible?
I have the following sheets:

-Part Database(it already works here in range C3:C11)

-Input(where the source of the Drop down list is located, in the code Range("I1") thats the header of the source DropDown list where below it there are the selectable values ranged I2:I10 but it keeps growing as i add more, code also pasted on this "Input" sheet)

-APM2

-APM3

-APM4 and so on...

Is it possible to change the code so that is works for example not only on range (Part Database!$C$3:$C$11), but also on lets say APM2!$D$5:$D$11, APM!3$K$8:$K$15....
Thanks for the help in advance!
To clear things up i made a workbook to demonstrate the problem. https://ufile.io/pu9jx

Comment: You need to insert `Worksheet_Change` sub to all worksheets where you want it to run. And remember updating reference to `Worksheets("Part Database")` according to the sheet's name.

Comment: I can't put the code on another worksheet because the source of the DropDown is on Sheet(Input) and 
For count_cells = 1 To Range("I1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1 <-this line refers to it.
What i need is to add more ranges to the code, but i dont know how:
Set rng = Worksheets("Part Database").Range("C3:C11") <- this range already works. i need 3 more ranges added to the code, but i dont know how to implement it:
Set rng = Worksheets("APM2").Range("D5:D11")
Set rng = Worksheets("APM3").Range("K8:K15")
Set rng = Worksheets("APM4").Range("F3:C11")
Sorry if im explaining it poorly.

Comment: This is correct so far. So if you want to have the same values in the specified ranges on all sheets, put this after `Next count_cells` (after you have updated the values for the dropdown list): `Worksheets("Part Database").Range("C3:C11").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("APM2").Range("D5:D11")` to copy the values to another sheet.